# Start chapter numbering at the third chapter

Tags: table-of-contents

I use the report class.
I have a total of 8 chapters, however I only want 6 chapters to have a number. So I want to start the numbering at the third chapter, and the first 2 chapters should only show the title in the table of contents. 
so basically i have the chapters:
abbreviations
preface
theoretical background
etc.

and i want the abbreviations and preface to show up in the TOC as only the title and start the numbering at theoretical background. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the starred version of sectioning command (`\chapter*`) here to prevent the numbering as well as the TOC entry.

However, in your case, you want to have the TOC listing, so must add it manually using `\addcontentsline` (see the short code)

Please note, that starred chapters do not use a `\cleardoublepage`, so they start at the next page.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{First}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{First}

\blindtext


\chapter*{Second}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Second}

\blindtext


\chapter{First numbered one}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit -- a more sophisticated version, adding an optional argument to `\chapter*` that goes to the TOC!**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}


%%% Redefine the chapter commands such that \chapter*[short_title]{Long title} is possible 
\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\unstarredchapter@opt}[2][]{%  
\LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredchapter@noopt}[1]{%
\unstarredchapter@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredchapter@opt}[2][]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#2}
\ifblank{#1}{}{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
}%

\newcommand{\starredchapter@noopt}[1]{%
\starredchapter@opt[]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\starredchapter@opt}{\starredchapter@noopt}
}%


\newcommand{\unstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarredchapter@opt}{\unstarredchapter@noopt}
}%

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}
}%
\makeatother



\tableofcontents



\chapter*[Abbreviations]{Abbreviations}

\blindtext


\chapter*[Preface]{Preface}

\blindtext


\chapter{Theoretical background}
\blindtext

\chapter*{A starred chapter with no toc entry}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user53965: I provided an improved version, such that `\addcontentsline` is not necessary at all (it is done automatically inside then)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
```

to have chapters numbers starting from 3.

To add your missing chapters to the table of contents you can use:

```
\setcounter{page}{4}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{1. Hello}

\setcounter{page}{14}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{2. world}
\setcounter{chapter}{5}
```

As far as I can see you need to generate at least one page for each chapter in order to get the page numbering correct in te table of contents.

Comment: Your solution shifts the chapter number and adds non existing chapters to the toc, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  Hmm, sorry I misread the question as I thought that's what the OP asked for...